# Get file location path in Android

Tags: android

My problem is that I cannot get a full path of a file in Android. I search on Google and find out this code which has a result nearly what I want:

```
public void openFolder()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
        + "/sdcard/");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/png");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
}
```

I choose file from "File Manager". After I access some folders and finally reach my file in "File Manager", the "File Manager" closes and no path is saved.

What should I do in order to save the path and file name? Ex: "/sdcard/Download/frame1.png".

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where do you want to save the path ?

Comment: I create a variable String myPath to save it. Later I will need to show it on TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you will need to implement `onActivityResult` as described in an example below.

Example: http://steveliles.github.io/returning_a_result_from_an_android_activity.html

Answer (score 0):

First you can assign a File object to your file as fileA.Then the file path should be path = fileA.getAbsolutePath();
You can store this String in your clipBoard using ClipboardManager.